# Silverlight 3d api

Tags: 3d

Is there an Silverlight 3d API ? or Isometric API ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This thread:](http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/t/1134.aspx)

> Currently there is no support for true hardware accelerated 3D in Silverlight. It is not possible to write 3D games that run in browser nor is the development model similar to Managed Direct3D. Any kind of 3D game will be very hard to port to Silverlight. Silverlight is more suitable for development of games, that are currently built using Adobe Flash.

I guess that's a no at the moment.
EDIT: It appears the thread I mentioned is slightly dated. So to some extent, there is hardware accelerated 3D.

Comment: That was true back in 2007 when that thread was started, but Silverlight at present does support hardware acceleration to some degree. Mentioned at the bottom of said thread is a library called Balder - you should check that out.

Answer (score 2):

Silverlight 3 introduced [`Projection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.projection(v=VS.95).aspx) which allows for 3D transformations of elements. And in Silverlight 4 it became hardware accelerated.

(There are a very limited number of things that Silverlight 3 and 4 will hardware accelerate - and lots of ways to accidentally turn it off or make it perform poorly.)

There are two projection elements: [`PlaneProjection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.planeprojection(v=VS.95).aspx) and  [`Matrix3DProjection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.matrix3dprojection(v=VS.95).aspx). The former is useful for making 3D interfaces. The latter will give you sufficient control to actually place elements in full 3D (providing you're pretty handy with your matrices).

This is a **far cry** from a 3D engine that renders triangles. You will be basically placing textured quads in 3D space.

Using this, a game that uses "2.5D" like Doom or Diablo 2 should be possible with *a lot* of work. It's worth pointing out that Silverlight as a whole is woefully inadequate for making games that require "fancy" graphics.

For a more generic 3D engine, you could take a look at the Silverlight version of [Balder](https://github.com/einari/Balder). Last time I looked, it was slow and buggy - although it seems to have improved since then. It does software rendering on Silverlight, so performance is going to limit you to the simplest of 3D environments.

---

**UPDATE**: Silverlight 5 now supports real 3D with an API that is very close to the one used by XNA.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check this book out at amazon:
[3D Game Development with Microsoft Silverlight 3: Beginner's Guide](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1847198929)